# laptop has no internet and network is limited access through WiFi, it works with cable

Tags: windows, networking, router, wireless-networking

If I connect my laptop (windows vista) on my router via cable than I have network and internet,

---

but if I do it via **WiFi** the network is identified as an **unknown network with limited access** and I can't ping the router, also I see other computers in my network folder but I can't ping them

Comment: What's your router brand/model?

Comment: TP-Link N router, this is his user guide http://www.tp-link.com/english/soft/2009101615370511.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was the atheros wifi driver, I had to update it